# How do I combine all arrays into one

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a loop function where I find all the IDs and each of the ID I will grab all of the details report.

I will store each of the IDs details in the 'reportData' array.

Currently it will print each of the array one by one.

I tried a lot of changes, but seems like my problem was just a simple logic placement.

```
function IDDetails()
{
  var ID = []
  for (row = 4; row < 150; row++)
  {
    var col = 4;
    var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeSheetTab = activeSheet.getSheetByName('Newsletter Report');
    var ID = activeSheetTab.getRange(row, col).getValue();
    if (ID.length != 0){
      var root = '';
      var endpoint1 = '';
      var endpoint2 = '';

      var params = 
      {
        'method': 'GET',
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'headers': {'Authorization': 'apikey ' + API_KEY}
      };
      try
      {  
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch();
        var data = response.getContentText();
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        var report = json['details'];
        var reportData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < report.length; i++)
        {
          reportData.push([
            ID,
            report[i]["item1"],
            report[i]["item2"],
            report[i]["item3"]
          ]); 
        }
      } catch(e) {
          Logger.log(e);
      }; 

     Logger.log(reportData);

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Details');
     var numRows = reportData.length;
     var numCols = reportData[0].length;
     sheet.getRange(2,1,numRows,numCols).setValues(reportData);
    }
    else {}
  }
}
```

But, what I want it to do is, store all the ID's details in one array lets call it 'reportDataALL'

Then print it as one.

Example result:

```
ID 1:

+---+---------+--------+--------+
|ID | item1   | item2  | item3  |
+---|---------+--------+--------+
| 1 | xxx     | yyy    | zzz    |
+---+---------+--------+--------+
| 1 | ooo     | rrr    | eee    |
+---+---------+--------+--------+
ID 2:
+---+---------+--------+--------+
|ID |item1    | item2  | item3  |
+---|---------+--------+--------+
| 2 | aaa     | bbb    | ccc    |
+---+---------+--------+--------+
| 2 | ggg     | ppp    | lll    |
+---+---------+--------+--------+
```

What I expected it to be:

```
ALL ID
reportDataALL

+---+---------+--------+---------+
|ID | item1   | item2  | item3   |
+---|---------+--------+---------+
| 1 | xxx     | yyy    | zzz     |
+---|---------+--------+---------+
| 1 | ooo     | rrr    | eee     |
+---+---------+--------+---------+
| 2 | aaa     | bbb    | ccc     |
+---+---------+--------+---------+
| 2 | ggg     | ppp    | lll     |
+---+---------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Could you provide the structure of your arrays? What do the different arrays that you try to combine look like? E.g. what is the structure of the report?

Comment: In your code, `ID` is an array.

Not sure why you would push the entire array in

    `reportData.push
        ([
            ID, ...
         ]);`

 Maybe you meant to push `ID[i]`, or `report[i]["id"]`?

Comment: @AnisR. since they're using `setValues()`, it needs the parameter to be a 2D array, so having ID as an array works there, if OP passed `ID[i]` there'd be an error.

Comment: @Andre array structure all the same.

Comment: @AnisR. I edit the question to explain more why I put the ID. I need the format data like that. And I pull the array from somewhere else, so theres more step inbetween.

Comment: 1. Provide sample  `report` structure, `ID` and 2. explain why you're looping from rows 4 to 149. 3. In addition, your ``Example result`` seems impossible, as you're  rewriting to the same range `A2:D`. There doesn't seem to be any logic in your code to calculate previous filled row/ID and then append ID2. Read [mre]

Comment: @TheMaster I updated the questions. Basically what I want to do is. 1) Find all the IDs. 2) Find all the details of each ID. 3) Print all ID's details together. Currently its printed 1-by-1. 

Another way to see it. 
var arrayA = [1, 2];
var arrayB = [3, 4];
var newArray = arrayA.concat(arrayB);

I want to contact the N-number of array. Instead of just A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you creates a lot of new tables but you should push them to the main result table

```
            function IDDetails()
            {
              var ID = []
              var reportData = [];            ///     <<<<<<<<< the target array
              for (row = 4; row < 150; row++)
              {
                var col = 4;
                var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                var activeSheetTab = activeSheet.getSheetByName('Newsletter Report');
                var ID = activeSheetTab.getRange(row, col).getValue();
                if (ID.length != 0){
                  var root = '';
                  var endpoint1 = '';
                  var endpoint2 = '';

                  var params =
                  {
                    'method': 'GET',
                    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
                    'headers': {'Authorization': 'apikey ' + API_KEY}
                  };
                  try
                  {
                    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch();
                    var data = response.getContentText();
                    var json = JSON.parse(data);
                    var report = json['details'];

                    for (var i = 0; i < report.length; i++)
                    var DETAILS=[]; //create next dimension

                    DETAILS[0]=id;  
                    DETAILS[1]=report[i]["item1"];  
                    DETAILS[2]=report[i]["item2"];  
                    DETAILS[3]=report[i]["item3"];  

                       reportData.push(DETAILS) ;

                  } catch(e) {
                      Logger.log(e);
                  };

                 Logger.log(reportData);

                 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Details');
                 var numRows = reportData.length;
                 var numCols = reportData[0].length;
                 sheet.getRange(2,1,numRows,numCols).setValues(reportData);
                }
                else {}
              }
            }
```

now you can access it with

```
   reportData[i][j]
```

if you want to have a 2 dimensional array

Same as a object

```
                   var DETAILS={}; //same as object

                    DETAILS[id]=id;  
                    DETAILS["item1"]=report[i]["item1"];  
                    DETAILS["item2"]=report[i]["item2"];  
                    DETAILS["item3"]=report[i]["item3"];  
                    reportData.push(DETAILS) ;
```

access via

```
               reportData[i].id
               reportData[i].item1
```

and so on

Comment: Thats the answer! Thank you very much sir!

Comment: no problem :) I deal at the moment with a lot of dynamic json elements so it yells in my eyes :)

Comment: 'dynamic json elements' I didn't Googled that when try to solve it. Will look futher into it.

Comment: Thank you. Will do.